# user removed, rep change

Tags: feature-request

Related: [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

How do I determine what user was removed.
Is there a way to have the related up/down-votes listed to see what questions comments were effected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't -- one of the most fundamental rules of SE is that voting is confidential.

You can only see when and from what posts you gain/lose reputation, [in your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/9082/argus?tab=reputation).

Comment: so there will be no way to see what questions/comments were effected all it shows is user removed no link to the effected question/comment

Comment: You may be able to deduce the answer if you can find a question where you know that things have changed. Or not, but the system will not help you.

Comment: ok thank you +1 Complete Answer