# More rep has changed than I can account for

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday I had 1693 rep, but when I logged on today I had only 1689 left. I went in to see if I'd gotten any downvotes. There weren't any, but I did have a *"post was removed"* notice - I ticked the *"show removed posts"* box at the bottom of the page because I've come across this before ([this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/incorrect-reputation-being-displayed) and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/user-removed-rep-change) meta question helped me figure things out then, I've already done the rep recalculation trigger).

However, that only accounts for a loss of 2 rep points and I seem to have lost 4. Is there anything else that can explain this?

Note: the amount of rep we're talking about is ludicrously small. So it's not the rep itself that bothers me, but the fact that I have no idea where it went.

Comment: Please remove [tag:reputation]. There's no need to create that extra tag, in my opinion.

Comment: Hmmm...can't find anything obvious.

Comment: @Dimension10 I didn't create it, it was already there. Seemed relevant?

Comment: @Wouter: This is the only question with the tag.

Comment: @Dimension10 I count 13: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation

Comment: @Wouter: Oh, I was on the wrong tab : ( Sorry.

Comment: @Dimension10 No problem ;)

Comment: @dmckee Does that mean it's likely some sort of bug?

Comment: The rep system has some of dark corners, and the reputation reporting system has a lot of them. It used to be that the reputation reporting system was *mostly* dark corners but that has gotten much better in the last 18 months or so. I'd be surprised if it was a honest to FSM bug in the reputation system, but unsurprised to learn it was a bug in the reporting system.

Comment: Are you aware of the reputation report at http://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation (while logged in)?

Comment: @dmckee Yeah, I haven't read it through, but I have tried the recalculation several hours ago I think.

Comment: Most of the time you shouldn't need recalculation these days. It used to be that reputation was maintained un-normalized and fixed from time to time, but that has changed: the value should be right *almost* all the time.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks for the explanation. So I guess the conclusion is this: that little slice of my rep pie isn't coming back but I shouldn't fear it will happen again (perhaps taking a bigger slice) anytime soon? :)

Comment: This happens quite commonly, but seriously, 2 rep isn't going to cost you any priveleges right?

Comment: @Dimension10 No I know, that's the reason for the "Note: ..." paragraph in the question. However, if it does indeed happen quite commonly, I *would* suggest trying to fix that little bug. Probably on the list already if it's a known bug, though likely not too high.